# Move windows in KDE via hotkeys

Tags: window, hotkeys, kde-plasma

I am using [Spectacle](http://spectacleapp.com/) on OSX. It's a cool program that allows to move and resize windows from **keyboard**. I looking for an analogue for KDE.

I need same functionality:

- resize window on half-screen by horizontal and vertical and move to screen edge (like as Windows 7). *it's feature supported by KDE.*
- resize window on (screen_size * 1/3) and (screen_size * 2/3) by horizontal and move to screen edge. ***how can I do this?***

[Spectacle usage example](http://gyazo.com/a1262476007896c4669dd2961fa42c37)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the TIL3R kwin script.  It gives KDE this ability.